# Call multiple commands in preamble with loop

Tags: loops, preamble

I want to call multiple commands in the preamble with a for loop in order to define the amount of commands at a different position in the code. So far my code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
% Here could be a list, e.g. \list = {Definition/definition, Axiom/axiom, ...}
% ...
\usepackage{thmtools} % boxes

\newcommand\mythm[3]{%
        \declaretheorem[thmbox=M, within = section,]{#1}%
        \newenvironment{#2}[1][]{%
            \begin{#1}[##1]%
            #3%
            \normalfont%
        }%
        {\end{#1}}%
}

\mythm{Definition}{definition}{}
\mythm{Axiom}{axiom}{}
\mythm{Notation}{notation}{}
% ...
% Here could be a for-loop

\begin{document}
    \begin{definition}[titel]
        Ceterum censeo Carthaginem esse delendam.
    \end{definition}
\end{document}
```

I wanted to create a list at the beginning of my preamble (e.g.`\list = {Definition/definition,...}` and then call `\mythm` with the content of the list (e.g.`\foreach \x/\y in \list {\mythm{\x}{\y}{}`). My Problem is, that I have no idea how to do it. I tried it with different syntax of for-loops, but none of these implementations was able to actually call `\mythm`. Can someone help my with that?

Comment: Problem solved?

Comment: Yes, sorry got ill and wasn't checking the web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in a few steps, but I don't see much gain.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{thmtools} % boxes

\NewDocumentCommand{\mythm}{mmm}{%
  % #1 = tag, #2 = environment name, #3 = body font selection
  \declaretheorem[
    thmbox=M,
    within=section,
    name=#1,
  ]{#2inner}
  \NewDocumentEnvironment{#2}{o}
   {% start
    \IfNoValueTF{##1}{\begin{#2inner}}{\begin{#2inner}[##1]}
    \normalfont
    \IfValueT{#3}{#3}%
   }
   {\end{#2inner}}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mythmslash}{>{\SplitArgument{2}{/}}m}{\mythm#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mythms}{>{\SplitList{,}}m}{\ProcessList{#1}{\mythmslash}}

\mythms{
  Definition/definition,
  Axiom/axiom,
  Notation/notation/\itshape
}

\begin{document}

\section{Title}

\begin{definition}[titel]
Ceterum censeo Carthaginem esse delendam.
\end{definition}

\begin{axiom}
Ceterum censeo Carthaginem esse delendam.
\end{axiom}

\begin{notation}[titel]
Ceterum censeo Carthaginem esse delendam.
\end{notation}

\end{document}
```

Note that your `\newenvironment` part makes the optional “title” argument actually mandatory, with the code above it is really optional.

I'd never use `thmbox`, to be honest.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `\clist_map_inline:nn` and `\NewDocumentCommand`'s `\SplitArgument` argument processor. Note that I added an `\ifstrempty` test inside your `\mythm` macro because the environments defined with  `\declaretheorem` don't like being passed an empty optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse} % only necessary if your LaTeX is older than 2020-10-01
\usepackage{etoolbox}           % for \ifstrempty
\usepackage{thmtools}           % for boxes

\newcommand{\mythm}[3]{%
  \declaretheorem[thmbox=M, within=section]{#1}%
  \newenvironment{#2}[1][]{%
      % The environments defined with \declaretheorem don't like being passed
      % an empty optional argument.
      \ifstrempty{##1}{\begin{#1}}{\begin{#1}[##1]}%
      #3\normalfont
  }%
  {\end{#1}}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \defineTheorems { m }
  {
    \clist_map_inline:nn {#1} { \defineOneTheorem {##1} }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \defineOneTheorem { > { \SplitArgument { 1 } { / } } m }
  { \mythm #1 { } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\defineTheorems{Definition/definition, Axiom/axiom, Notation/notation}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\begin{definition}[titel]
  Ceterum censeo Carthaginem esse delendam.
\end{definition}

\begin{axiom}
  covfefe
\end{axiom}

\begin{axiom}[foo]
  The ``foo'' axiom.
\end{axiom}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for my late response, got pretty ill. Thank you for the helpful answer! One question: Is there a way to call ```\defineTheorems{...}``` or set the wanted parameters  before ```\newcommand{\mythm}[3]{%```? I tried ```\newcommand{\tmp}{Definition/definition, ...} ... defineTheorems{\tmp}``` but that does not work :c

Comment: That would work with `\expandafter\defineTheorems\expandafter{\tmp}`, but since there would be a bunch of things executed between `\newcommand{\tmp}{...}` and `\tmp`'s use, I'd choose a macro name that is less likely to be accidentally overwritten by unrelated code (e.g., `\my@theorem@defs` or something like that).

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! Because people were wondering: I'm working on a template, which can handle multiple styles and has some simple options. I have no idea if it is good and will be used by someone else... Is there a way to discuss something like that?

Comment: Sorry, I can't say—not very interested in templates myself.